# Смена экранов движением пальца (swipe)

Tags: android

Как сделать так, чтобы, когда пользователь делает движение пальем (swipe) влево, появляkся второй фрагмент?

Comment: либо `GestureListener` http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/gestures/detector.html

Comment: Вы можете сделать свой кастомный жест, по ссылке что привел @miha_dev, чтобы именно только когда свайп влево и на определенное растояние срабатывал event и в обработчике уже делать что угодно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ViewPager` называется:
http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html
Только работает он не с `Activity`, а с `Fragment`

Comment: @nexus2014su, я не писал про `SwipeDetector`, в первый раз слышу.